# Is there a way to search for a PHP function in all of my documents in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, search, visual-studio-code

Is there an easy way to search for a PHP function in all of my documents?

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: I use visual studio code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. How fast you receive an answer depends on how good your question is.
Please read the below article on how to ask a good question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @hendrik-eg https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Refer Rich Languages Editing -> Go to definition. F12 is the keyboard shortcut, I guess

Comment: I looking for a way to search in several files at once. Maybe with the terminal. (I use The Silver Searcher in the terminal but I don't cant find the function with it.)

Comment: All of your files *open right now in VS Code*? Or all your files on your computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your using **"Sublime Text 3"** in it click `ctrl` + `f`. then you wil see input write there "function <name_of_function>".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG8f4.png)

And if your using **"Visual Studio Code"** your can use the same `ctrl` + `f` and on top of that you can search in all of the files in your project, for that you need to click to serch icon in sidebar, there you will see input, write there what you need to find.

**Using `ctrl` + `f`:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAWCM.png)

**Using sidebar search:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGj6x.png)

your can search in google how to do this in other code editors (if you have other code editor)